# Split a stream of data into different lists based on 2 different conditions in JAVA using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of Doubles (Temperatures). Say:

1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, ........., 20.0

I need to write a function `countTemperatures(t1,t2,range)` which should print a list which contains two pairs: 1) temperature t1 paired with the number of times a temperature in the interval **[t1-r..t1+r]** has been measured and 2) temperature t2 paired with the number of times a temperature in the interval **[t2-r..t2+r]** has been measured.

Example: countTemperatures(17.0,10.0,2.0) should return the list ((17.0,5), (10.0,5)) (because there are in total 5 measurements in the range between 17.0-2.0 (15) and 17.0+2.0 (19). I.e., 15,16,17,18,19. Simillarly for 2nd pair.

I need to demonstrate MapReduce(without any framework) and by only using java 8 streams.

I came up with the below:

```
## List<Double> temperature = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ......, 20.0]

List<Double> temp = temperature.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> t>=(t1-r) && t<=(t1+r)));
System.out.println(temp.get(true));
```

I actually wanted to get 2 lists with the values filled based on conditions given above. and then thought of using reduce() or count() to get the answer. But I am new to Java and stuck on this question of my assignment as i dont know how to proceed further. I am getting confused by all the videos and different type of questions.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy` are the right start.  Look at the types they return.

Comment: Why do you need a stream? Isn't the count always to be equal to `(2 * range) +1 `?

Comment: why not stream `temperatures` twice and `count` the occurrence for respective `tn` range?

Comment: countTemperatures takes only two temprature parameters but you have a list, I don't sync both. `list of Doubles` and `countTemperatures(t1,t2,range)` how do you pick two temp from list

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this?

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Double> tmps = new ArrayList<>();
        for (double i = 1.0;i<=20.0;i++){
            tmps.add(i);
        }
        List<Double> param = new ArrayList<>();
        param.add(17.0);
        param.add(10.0);
        param.add(2.0);
        System.out.println(countBykey(param,tmps));
    }

    public static List<List<Double>> countByKey(List<Double> param,List<Double> tmps){
        List<List<Double>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0;i<2;i++){
            int finalI = i;
            List<Double> e = new ArrayList<>();
            e.add(param.get(finalI));
            e.add((double) (int) tmps.stream().filter(aDouble -> (aDouble >= (param.get(finalI) - param.get(2)) &&
                    (aDouble <= (param.get(finalI) + param.get(2))))).count());
            res.add(e);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

output:

```
[[17.0, 5.0], [10.0, 5.0]]
```